# How to decompress this file

Tags: decompress

I'm trying to figure out how this old game is (de)compressing files, but I don't have much knowledge about file compression.
I tried running the game from a debug tool to see if I could spot something in the assembly, but that's way over my head..Also tried Ghidra but didn't bring me any closer. I can pinpoint roughly in the gmae code where it's reading file headers and starting allocating memory/decompressing, but what actually happens is a mystery.

The smallest compressed file is just 5kb, I uploaded it here: https://ufile.io/scibn9hp

The game is from 1996. Can anyone point me in the right direction for learning this stuff? Should I try understanding the program, or is it possible to understand the compression by just messing with the file?

Comment: What game is it? If it's from 1996 then someone may have figured it out already. Examining the file in a hex editor, you can see `CWE sprite` in the file header - I Googled that and found this: https://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=21665 - might be a start.

Comment: It's called Fire Fight..the problem is in decompressing the .VOL, sadly the game extractor software doesn't support this game

Comment: Looks like a different user on the same forum claims to have extracted some .vol files - https://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?p=161231 - probably worth seeing if they're still active and willing to share their program.

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out, maybe it can help me on my way

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging on forums and found a repo that has code in it to decode this file (as well as some other formats by the same game studio): https://github.com/alcexhim/UniversalEditor